# Usage of Websocket, STOMP in flutter application

Tags: flutter, stomp

While trying to work with STOMP, websockets, facing issue for "packages get" after updating pubspec with required stomp/websocket details. I have tried for stomp, stompdart, websocket none of them worked.
Error observed while running "packages get" is
"The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.4.0.flutter-4eb879133a.

Because project_name depends on stompdart >=0.0.2 which requires SDK version >=1.5.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub upgrade failed (1)"

If I try to downgrade flutter version then it has thrown exception informing 'current project needs SDK version > 2.0.0

Please help to clear the issue or suggest some other way as I am using STOMP at server end.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue, it can be solved in two ways:

1. solved it by adding this to my yaml file :

   dependency_overrides:
     stomp: ^0.7.3

   dependencies:

   stomp: ^0.7.3

   flutter:
       sdk: flutter

using the dependency_overrides works.

Secondly by running "pub upgrade" in your project directory

https://github.com/rikulo/stomp/issues/18#issuecomment-435748215

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a definitive answer, but it may help you.
I forked a chinese library that seems to work named JStomp and did some translations. Let me know if it work since I am also interested to be able to work with STOMP on Flutter.
Here's my fork:  https://github.com/raedcran/flutter_jstomp